# X is reflexive, so X is Weakly complete.

Tags: functional-analysis

Plese, help for this questions

"X is reflexive, so X is Weakly complete."

Thank you.

Comment: Define *everything* and take a closer look.

Comment: Also, you mean *reflexive*, not reflective.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A google search should help you out here: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~bwick6/teaching/math6338/math6338_hw4.pdf

Specifically see attached.  I've posted pics of the solution from the site given above.

[image]

[image]